# SQL finding duplicates by grouping on ALL columns

Tags: sql, duplicates

Is there a way to find duplicates in a table that do not require to specify all/some fields?
I need to do that on several tables and would like to have common code (simple as possible) that could be used in a loop, (just changing tablename).

so basically I was looking for something equivalent to:

```
SELECT *
, COUNT(*) TotalCount
FROM tableName
GROUP BY *
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
```

Is there any way to do so?

Comment: have you tried dynamic sql?

Comment: Why you are doing this ? IF you have the primary key column/columns or uniq key constraint on column/columns only grouping on them would work. If you dont have the primary key on table then you are doing something very much wrong way.

Comment: there is no primary key. The table stores imported data.  Idea is to identify possible duplicated rows withouth knowing the column names.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Answer (score 0):

try this but do take backup before trying

```
delete T from
(
select row_number() over(order by item) as row_number, * from @t
) T
where row_number not in 
(
select min(row_number) from (select row_number() over(order by item) as row_number, * from tableName) T 
group by item
)
```

i took this from a example from [here](http://beyondrelational.com/modules/2/blogs/70/posts/10802/multipurpose-rownumber-function.aspx)